# query is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM functions 
  WHERE isEnabled=1 AND isPrivate=0
  AND user_name=high
  AND function_description LIKE '%test%'
```

`#1054 - Unknown column 'isEnabled' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Put simply, there's no column named `isEnabled` in your table named `functions`. Looking at the naming convention for the rest of your query is it possible you mean `is_enabled` and `is_private`?

Comment: And user_name=high looks suspecious, user_name='high' seems more like it

Comment: Post your table definition - `SHOW CREATE TABLE functions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting backticks around your isEnabled field name :

```
WHERE `isEnabled`=1
```

The isEnable field have the E Capital letter ...

Comment: Is `isEnabled` a keyword? Is there another reason backticks would help? What difference do capital letters make?